# Assume variable = 0 if textbox is empty C#

Tags: c#

This may be the incorrect way of asking this but I need to figure out how to have the value that I am parsing in from a textbox to be 0 if it is left blank.

I have two textbox's (LaborCharge & PartsCharge)

the user does not need to enter in a value for the charges. Assuming that they left one of both of the textboxes blank, I want the value that I am parsing out of the textbox to = 0 so I can use it to calculate a total for labor and parts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use something like the following:

```
int charge = 0;
int.TryParse(LaborCharge.Text, out charge);
...
```

Try parse will set charge to zero if the conversion fails due to the string being null, empty or not containing a number. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Yes, it will set its argument to `default(int)`. An `out` parameter must be assigned prior to the function returning. +1

Comment: This will set the value to 0 if "cat" somehow ends up in the text box too, which may or may not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

compare the TextBox's Values with [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or if you are running .Net 4.0  [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be better suited for you.

```
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LaborCharge.Text))
            //Set your variable to zero
        else
           //Process your code
```

Comment: Perhaps `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` would be better, but I would prefer `TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set a default value of 0 to each TextBox you create. 
this way you don't have to deal with a null value, which sometimes causes some difficulties if you don't pay attention (late night programming...).

I find that users usually don't mind 0 values in empty boxes, and it is much easier later on to write:

```
if(TextBox.Text = "0")
 // enter your code in here
```

Comment: Technically you are doing an assignment there, which would work, but will have unintended side effects :) (and always return false if it compiles at all). Also, what if the user manually clears the TextBox?